# What to do when someone's posting answers which suggest upgrading to an EoL release

Tags: discussion, posts

A new user just posted the (almost) same answer, viz.

> Update to Ubuntu 16.10 That should solve this (issue).

to the following two different questions where OP is/was using 16.04

[I am not able to find other people on my local network when playing Counter Strike 1.6](https://askubuntu.com/a/964204/)

[My Ubuntu 16.04 does not recognize power supply plug/unplug instantaneously](https://askubuntu.com/a/964207/)

Surprisingly the answers got 2 upvotes each soon.

While these answers are not technically spam or not-an-answer the suggestion is pretty ill-advised.

Is there anything we can/should do other than downvoting and/or leaving a comment?

---

Also another new user posted the following answer

> Updating to Ubuntu 17.04 should solve this.

to those same two questions ([first](https://askubuntu.com/a/964210/) & [second](https://askubuntu.com/a/964214/)) and got 1 upvote each. Looks fishy.

Comment: I downvoted the 16.10 ones (and upvoted your comment and voted to delete one of them that appeared in the low quality posts queue) and commented to request info on the 17.04 ones. It does indeed seem odd to me that these posts were upvoted ([mentioned it](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40504202#40504202) in the Downboat a little earlier) PS, congrats on 2k

Comment: Stinks of sock puppetry

Comment: @muru And if it is, the system will notice it and do what exactly? Just delete the votes? Or also delete the posts? Even delete the users?

Comment: @dessert nothing. Serial voting is automatically reversed. Sock puppetry of a large enough scale becomes visible as voting patterns to moderators, but no automatic action takes place. And this is small scale.

Comment: Look at this https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/13956/is-type-2-diabetes-reversible. Spamming as well.

Comment: I flagged Sandeep's SO profile for mod attention.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is now handled here on Ask Ubuntu.

You're also free to flag posts for moderator attention if you think there are suspicious patterns of users or sockpuppets or such.  We can investigate these far more easily than standard users and determine if this is actually the case or not.  (However, flags are NOT to be used for incorrect answers - downvotes only, there)

Please bring moderation issues on other sites up with only those sites' moderators, and please don't use this meta thread as a dropbox for "They're also on [other site]" logging of their activities.

Comment: It turned out to be a case of sockpuppetry which I didn't expect at the beginning to be honest. My first concern was someone posting a potentially harmful idea as upgrading to an EoL release as an answer. My query was how to deal with this kind of answer in general. Can we flag as "not an answer"? Or as "very low quality"? Or should we just downvote and comment?

Comment: @pomsky flagging is not for incorrect answers. Those should be down voted